# Qt, how can I get rid of a semantic issue from Qt include files

Tags: c++, qt

I'm unable to solve why I'm getting the issue below for the includes: QWidget, QPoint, and QDialog

[image]

My project still works, it's just annoying to look at for me.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: What compiler and version are you using in your project? Is it compatible with the Qt version you have?